# Can I have an example of pairwise comparisons of data against a within-subject factor?

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, repeated-measures

Here is an ANOVA model with one between-subject factor (condition; 4 levels) and one within-subject factor (trial_seq; 20 levels).

```
amod = aov(decision_quality ~ condition*trial_seq +
       Error(user_id/trial_seq), data = d.task1)
summary(amod)
```

I want to do  a pairwise analysis for both the between-subject factor and the within-subject factor. I found that it is not straightforward to use a function like TukeyHSD() for a within-subject factor.  I researched this problem and found some suggestions in [another thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575/post-hocs-for-within-subjects-tests).

However, my lack of statistical background prevented me from fully understanding vignettes coming with the multcomp package. Anyway, I tried some random statements like:

```
summary(glht(amod, linfct = mcp(trial_seq = "Tukey")))
```

However, it generates the following error:

```
Error in model.matrix.aovlist(model) : 
  ‘glht’ does not support objects of class ‘aovlist’
Error in summary(glht(amod, linfct = mcp(trial_seq = "Tukey"))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for     
function 'summary': Error in factor_contrasts(model) : 
  no ‘model.matrix’ method for ‘model’ found!
```

- What did I do wrong?

Comment: I found another suggestion at http://yatani.jp/HCIstats/PostHoc saying simply use pairwise.t.test(decision_quality, trial_seq, p.adj="bonferroni", paired=T) for the post-hoc test of the within-subject factor. I am not sure if this is a correct.

Comment: According to http://www.uky.edu/ComputingCenter/SSTARS/www/documentation/MultipleComparisons_3.htm#b23, SAS provide the SIMULATE option for general mixed and repeated measures models. Is there anything equivalent in R?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message exemplifies, `glht` does not accept objects of type `aovlist`. In other words, there is no way of running contrasts with an ANOVA specified via `aov`.

To achieve what you want you would need to use another way of specifiying the repeated measures ANOVA, namels via `lme` in the `lmer` package (using a compound symmteric correlation structure). For a description see [my answer to this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15526/442). Because `glht` can handle `lme` objects.

If you have problems implementing this procedure please be specific on where your problems are.