# Between group comparison for every level of within factor

Tags: r, anova, post-hoc, lme4-nlme

If I use `lme` for mixed ANOVA as follow

```
lme_model=lme(dv ~ between*within, data frame, random=~1|ID, correlation=corCompSymm(form=~1|ID))
```

how can I perform between group comparison for every level of within factor?

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15526/how-to-perform-a-4-by-4-mixed-anova-with-between-and-within-subjects-contrasts/15532#15532) great answer advice to use `anova` with `L` argument. But I can't understand how.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try the `lsmeans` and `multcomp` packages ?

Comment: Thank you. `Lsmeans` is what I am looking for. `multcomp` with `summary(glht(lme_model, linfct=mcp(between = "Tukey")), test = adjusted(type = "fdr"))` lead to warning `In mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) :  covariate interactions found -- default contrast might be inappropriate`. Is `lsmeans` concerned about covariate interactions?

Comment: I think there are significant interactions in your fitting and then you get a warning about comparing main effects in such a situation because this comparison is possibly meaningless.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your last thought. I decided to use `lsmeans(lme_model, pairwise ~ between | within)`.

Comment: When you have a model with two factors, say A and B, it is not pertinent to assess the effect of these factors when the interaction A:B is significant. I think `multcomp`and/or `lsmeans` returns a warning in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for post-hoc tests you should find additional functions in R such as `TukeyHSD` for example.

If you want to perform planned comparisons with your anova, I am used to enter directly contrast codes in the linear model.

I found a simple example [here](https://www.google.lu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CE0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.smu.edu%2Fkyler%2Fcourses%2F7311%2Fplanned_4up.pdf&ei=VfgZUeXODOWX1AWQmIDIDA&usg=AFQjCNGKfmmMyEgNudm40KezfC-w3tW3Sw)