# Appropriate post-hoc test after a mixed design anova in R

Tags: r, post-hoc, mixed-model

I have a mixed design ANOVA, with a 2 level between-subject and a 7 level within subject variable. What is the appropriate post-hoc test after a significant ANOVA?

I'd like to see R code in the response.

Comment: There are a number of relevant questions with answers on this side: (one)[http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14078/442], (two)[http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15526/442]. Actually, your questions seems identical to the second one, hence I suggest closing.

Comment: OK, so if I have an ANOVA defined as `aov(value~Condition*Scenario+Error(Subject/Scenario))`, how do I define it using `lme`?