# What is the lme4::lmer equivalent of a three-way repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

My question is based on [this response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13816/442) which showed which `lme4::lmer` model corresponds to a two-way repeated measures ANOVA:

```
require(lme4)
set.seed(1234)
d <- data.frame(
    y = rnorm(96),
    subject = factor(rep(1:12, 4)),
    a = factor(rep(1:2, each=24)),
    b = factor(rep(rep(1:2, each=12))),
    c = factor(rep(rep(1:2, each=48))))

# standard two-way repeated measures ANOVA:
summary(aov(y~a*b+Error(subject/(a*b)), d[d$c == "1",]))

# corresponding lmer call:
anova(lmer(y ~ a*b+(1|subject) + (1|a:subject) + (1|b:subject), d[d$c == "1",]))
```

My question now is on how to extend this to the case of a three-way ANOVA:

```
summary(aov(y~a*b*c+Error(subject/(a*b*c)), d))
## [...]
## Error: subject:a:b:c
##           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
## a:b:c      1  0.101  0.1014   0.115  0.741
## Residuals 11  9.705  0.8822
```

The natural extension as well as versions thereof do not match the ANOVA results:

```
anova(lmer(y ~ a*b*c +(1|subject) + (1|a:subject) + (1|b:subject) + (1|c:subject), d))
## [...]
## a:b:c  1 0.1014  0.1014  0.1500

anova(lmer(y ~ a*b*c +(1|subject) + (1|a:subject) + (1|b:subject) + (1|c:subject) + 
               (1|a:b:subject) + (1|a:c:subject) + (1|b:c:subject), d))
## [...]
## a:b:c  1 0.1014  0.1014  0.1539
```

Note that a very similar question has been asked [before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/99765/442). However, it was missing example data (which is provided here).

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want your two level model to be `y ~ a*b + (1 + a*b|subject), d[d$c == "1",]` ? Or perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: @RasmusBååth Go Ahead and try to fit it, `lmer` will complain as the random effects are not identified any more. Initially I also thought that this is the model I want, but it is not. If you compare the lmer model I propose for the 2-way case with the standard ANOVA you will see that the F-values **exactly** match. As said in the response I linked.

Comment: For the three-way problem, the first `lmer` model that you wrote (which excludes the random two-way interactions) is *not* expected to be equivalent to a 3-way RM-ANOVA, but the second one that you wrote (which includes the random two-way interactions) should be. As for why there is a discrepancy even with that model, I have a hunch about what the problem is, going to grab dinner then will look at the toy dataset some more.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that the last model you wrote,

```
anova(lmer(y ~ a*b*c +(1|subject) + (1|a:subject) + (1|b:subject) + (1|c:subject) + 
           (1|a:b:subject) + (1|a:c:subject) + (1|b:c:subject), d))
```

I believe is "in principle" correct, although it is a strange parameterization that doesn't always seem to work well in actual practice.

As for why the output that you get from this model is discrepant with the `aov()` output, I think there are two reasons.

1. Your simple simulated dataset is pathological in that the best-fitting model is one that implies negative variance components, which mixed models fit by `lmer()` (and most other mixed model programs) won't allow.
2. Even with a non-pathological dataset, the way you have the model set up, as mentioned above, does not always seem to work well in practice, although I must admit I don't really understand why. It is also just generally strange in my opinion, but that's another story.

Let me first demonstrate the parameterization that I prefer on your initial two-way ANOVA example. Assume that your dataset `d` is loaded. Your model (note that I changed from dummy to contrast codes) was:

```
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
mod1 <- lmer(y ~ a*b+(1|subject) + (1|a:subject) + (1|b:subject),
         data = d[d$c == "1",])
anova(mod1)
# Analysis of Variance Table
#     Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# a    1 2.20496 2.20496  3.9592
# b    1 0.13979 0.13979  0.2510
# a:b  1 1.23501 1.23501  2.2176
```

which worked fine here in that it matched the `aov()` output. The model that I prefer involves two changes: manually contrast-coding the factors so that we are not working with R factor objects (which I recommend doing in 100% of cases), and specifying the random effects differently:

```
d <- within(d, {
  A <- 2*as.numeric(paste(a)) - 3
  B <- 2*as.numeric(paste(b)) - 3
  C <- 2*as.numeric(paste(c)) - 3
})
mod2 <- lmer(y ~ A*B + (1|subject)+(0+A|subject)+(0+B|subject),
             data = d[d$c == "1",])
anova(mod2)
# Analysis of Variance Table
# Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# A    1 2.20496 2.20496  3.9592
# B    1 0.13979 0.13979  0.2510
# A:B  1 1.23501 1.23501  2.2176

logLik(mod1)
# 'log Lik.' -63.53034 (df=8)
logLik(mod2)
# 'log Lik.' -63.53034 (df=8)
```

The two approaches are totally equivalent in the simple 2-way problem. Now we'll move to a 3-way problem. I mentioned earlier that the example dataset you gave was pathological. So what I want to do before addressing your example dataset is to first generate a dataset from an actual variance components model (i.e., where non-zero variance components are built into the true model). First I will show how my preferred parameterization seems to work better than the one you proposed. Then I will demonstrate another way of estimating the variance components which does *not* impose that they must be non-negative. Then we will be in a position to see the problem with the original example dataset.

The new dataset will be identical in structure except we will have 50 subjects:

```
set.seed(9852903)
d2 <- expand.grid(A=c(-1,1), B=c(-1,1), C=c(-1,1), sub=seq(50))
d2 <- merge(d2, data.frame(sub=seq(50), int=rnorm(50), Ab=rnorm(50),
  Bb=rnorm(50), Cb=rnorm(50), ABb=rnorm(50), ACb=rnorm(50), BCb=rnorm(50)))
d2 <- within(d2, {
  y <- int + (1+Ab)*A + (1+Bb)*B + (1+Cb)*C + (1+ABb)*A*B +
    (1+ACb)*A*C + (1+BCb)*B*C + A*B*C + rnorm(50*2^3)
  a <- factor(A)
  b <- factor(B)
  c <- factor(C)
})
```

The F-ratios we want to match are:

```
aovMod1 <- aov(y ~ a*b*c + Error(factor(sub)/(a*b*c)), data = d2)
tab <- lapply(summary(aovMod1), function(x) x[[1]][1,2:4])
do.call(rbind, tab)
#                          Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# Error: factor(sub)       439.48    8.97        
# Error: factor(sub):a     429.64  429.64  32.975
# Error: factor(sub):b     329.48  329.48  27.653
# Error: factor(sub):c     165.44  165.44  17.924
# Error: factor(sub):a:b   491.33  491.33  49.694
# Error: factor(sub):a:c   305.46  305.46  41.703
# Error: factor(sub):b:c   466.09  466.09  40.655
# Error: factor(sub):a:b:c 392.76  392.76 448.101
```

Here are our two models:

```
mod3 <- lmer(y ~ a*b*c + (1|sub)+(1|a:sub)+(1|b:sub)+(1|c:sub)+
  (1|a:b:sub)+(1|a:c:sub)+(1|b:c:sub), data = d2)
anova(mod3)
# Analysis of Variance Table
#       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# a      1  32.73   32.73  34.278
# b      1  21.68   21.68  22.704
# c      1  12.53   12.53  13.128
# a:b    1  60.93   60.93  63.814
# a:c    1  50.38   50.38  52.762
# b:c    1  57.30   57.30  60.009
# a:b:c  1 392.76  392.76 411.365

mod4 <- lmer(y ~ A*B*C + (1|sub)+(0+A|sub)+(0+B|sub)+(0+C|sub)+
  (0+A:B|sub)+(0+A:C|sub)+(0+B:C|sub), data = d2)
anova(mod4)
# Analysis of Variance Table
#       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# A      1  28.90   28.90  32.975
# B      1  24.24   24.24  27.653
# C      1  15.71   15.71  17.924
# A:B    1  43.56   43.56  49.694
# A:C    1  36.55   36.55  41.703
# B:C    1  35.63   35.63  40.655
# A:B:C  1 392.76  392.76 448.101

logLik(mod3)
# 'log Lik.' -984.4531 (df=16)
logLik(mod4)
# 'log Lik.' -973.4428 (df=16)
```

As we can see, only the second method matches the output from `aov()`, although the first method is at least in the ballpark. The second method also achieves a higher log-likelihood. I am not sure why these two methods give different results, as again I think they are "in principle" equivalent, but maybe it is for some numerical/computational reasons. Or maybe I am mistaken and they are not equivalent even in principle.

Now I will show another way of estimating the variance components based on traditional ANOVA ideas. Basically we will take the expected mean square equations for your design, substitute in the observed values of the mean squares, and solve for the variance components. To get the expected mean squares we will use an R function that I wrote a few years ago, called `EMS()`, which is documented [HERE](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/18603-Share-your-functions-amp-code?p=82050&viewfull=1#post82050). Below I assume the function is loaded already.

```
# prepare coefficient matrix
r <- 1 # number of replicates
s <- 50 # number of subjects
a <- 2 # number of levels of A
b <- 2 # number of levels of B
c <- 2 # number of levels of C
CT <- EMS(r ~ a*b*c*s, random="s")
expr <- strsplit(CT[CT != ""], split="")
expr <- unlist(lapply(expr, paste, collapse="*"))
expr <- sapply(expr, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
CT[CT != ""] <- expr
CT[CT == ""] <- 0
mode(CT) <- "numeric"
# residual variance and A*B*C*S variance are confounded in
# this design, so remove the A*B*C*S variance component
CT <- CT[-15,-2]
CT
#        VarianceComponent
# Effect  e b:c:s a:c:s a:b:s a:b:c c:s b:s a:s b:c a:c a:b s   c   b   a
#   a     1     0     0     0     0   0   0   4   0   0   0 0   0   0 200
#   b     1     0     0     0     0   0   4   0   0   0   0 0   0 200   0
#   c     1     0     0     0     0   4   0   0   0   0   0 0 200   0   0
#   s     1     0     0     0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0 8   0   0   0
#   a:b   1     0     0     2     0   0   0   0   0   0 100 0   0   0   0
#   a:c   1     0     2     0     0   0   0   0   0 100   0 0   0   0   0
#   b:c   1     2     0     0     0   0   0   0 100   0   0 0   0   0   0
#   a:s   1     0     0     0     0   0   0   4   0   0   0 0   0   0   0
#   b:s   1     0     0     0     0   0   4   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0
#   c:s   1     0     0     0     0   4   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0
#   a:b:c 1     0     0     0    50   0   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0
#   a:b:s 1     0     0     2     0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0
#   a:c:s 1     0     2     0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0
#   b:c:s 1     2     0     0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0
#   e     1     0     0     0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0

# get mean squares
(MSmod <- summary(aov(y ~ a*b*c*factor(sub), data=d2)))
#                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
# a                  1  429.6   429.6
# b                  1  329.5   329.5
# c                  1  165.4   165.4
# factor(sub)       49  439.5     9.0
# a:b                1  491.3   491.3
# a:c                1  305.5   305.5
# b:c                1  466.1   466.1
# a:factor(sub)     49  638.4    13.0
# b:factor(sub)     49  583.8    11.9
# c:factor(sub)     49  452.2     9.2
# a:b:c              1  392.8   392.8
# a:b:factor(sub)   49  484.5     9.9
# a:c:factor(sub)   49  358.9     7.3
# b:c:factor(sub)   49  561.8    11.5
# a:b:c:factor(sub) 49   42.9     0.9
MS <- MSmod[[1]][,"Mean Sq"]

# solve
ans <- solve(CT, MS)
cbind(rev(ans[c(grep("e",names(ans)),grep("s",names(ans)))])/
        c(1,2,2,2,4,4,4,1))
# s     1.0115549
# a:s   1.5191114
# b:s   1.3797937
# c:s   1.0441351
# a:b:s 1.1263331
# a:c:s 0.8060402
# b:c:s 1.3235126
# e     0.8765093
summary(mod4)
# Random effects:
#  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  sub      (Intercept) 1.0116   1.0058  
#  sub.1    A           1.5191   1.2325  
#  sub.2    B           1.3798   1.1746  
#  sub.3    C           1.0441   1.0218  
#  sub.4    A:B         1.1263   1.0613  
#  sub.5    A:C         0.8060   0.8978  
#  sub.6    B:C         1.3235   1.1504  
#  Residual             0.8765   0.9362  
# Number of obs: 400, groups:  sub, 50
```

Okay, now we will return to the original example. The F-ratios we are trying to match are:

```
aovMod2 <- aov(y~a*b*c+Error(subject/(a*b*c)), data = d)
tab <- lapply(summary(aovMod2), function(x) x[[1]][1,2:4])
do.call(rbind, tab)
#                       Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# Error: subject       13.4747  1.2250        
# Error: subject:a      1.4085  1.4085  1.2218
# Error: subject:b      3.1180  3.1180  5.5487
# Error: subject:c      6.3809  6.3809  5.2430
# Error: subject:a:b    1.5706  1.5706  2.6638
# Error: subject:a:c    1.0907  1.0907  1.5687
# Error: subject:b:c    1.4128  1.4128  2.3504
# Error: subject:a:b:c  0.1014  0.1014  0.1149
```

Here are our two models:

```
mod5 <- lmer(y ~ a*b*c + (1|subject)+(1|a:subject)+(1|b:subject)+
  (1|c:subject)+(1|a:b:subject)+(1|a:c:subject)+(1|b:c:subject),
  data = d)
anova(mod5)
# Analysis of Variance Table
#       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# a      1 0.8830  0.8830  1.3405
# b      1 3.1180  3.1180  4.7334
# c      1 3.8062  3.8062  5.7781
# a:b    1 1.5706  1.5706  2.3844
# a:c    1 0.9620  0.9620  1.4604
# b:c    1 1.4128  1.4128  2.1447
# a:b:c  1 0.1014  0.1014  0.1539

mod6 <- lmer(y ~ A*B*C + (1|subject)+(0+A|subject)+(0+B|subject)+
  (0+C|subject)+(0+A:B|subject)+(0+A:C|subject)+
  (0+B:C|subject), data = d)
anova(mod6)
# Analysis of Variance Table
#       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
# a      1 0.8830  0.8830  1.3405
# b      1 3.1180  3.1180  4.7334
# c      1 3.8062  3.8062  5.7781
# a:b    1 1.5706  1.5706  2.3844
# a:c    1 0.9620  0.9620  1.4604
# b:c    1 1.4128  1.4128  2.1447
# a:b:c  1 0.1014  0.1014  0.1539

logLik(mod5)
# 'log Lik.' -135.0351 (df=16)
logLik(mod6)
# 'log Lik.' -134.9191 (df=16)
```

In this case the two models yield basically the same results, although the second method has a very slightly higher log-likelihood. Neither method matches `aov()`. But let's look at what we get when we solve for the variance components as we did above, using the ANOVA procedure that does not constrain variance components to be non-negative (but which can only be used in balanced designs with no continuous predictors and no missing data; the classical ANOVA assumptions).

```
# prepare coefficient matrix
r <- 1 # number of replicates
s <- 12 # number of subjects
a <- 2 # number of levels of A
b <- 2 # number of levels of B
c <- 2 # number of levels of C
CT <- EMS(r ~ a*b*c*s, random="s")
expr <- strsplit(CT[CT != ""], split="")
expr <- unlist(lapply(expr, paste, collapse="*"))
expr <- sapply(expr, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
CT[CT != ""] <- expr
CT[CT == ""] <- 0
mode(CT) <- "numeric"
# residual variance and A*B*C*S variance are confounded in
# this design, so remove the A*B*C*S variance component
CT <- CT[-15,-2]

# get mean squares
MSmod <- summary(aov(y ~ a*b*c*subject, data=d))
MS <- MSmod[[1]][,"Mean Sq"]

# solve
ans <- solve(CT, MS)
cbind(rev(ans[c(grep("e",names(ans)),grep("s",names(ans)))])/
        c(1,2,2,2,4,4,4,1))
# s      0.04284033
# a:s    0.03381648
# b:s   -0.04004005
# c:s    0.04184887
# a:b:s -0.03657940
# a:c:s -0.02337501
# b:c:s -0.03514457
# e      0.88224787
summary(mod6)
# Random effects:
#  Groups    Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
#  subject   (Intercept) 7.078e-02 2.660e-01
#  subject.1 A           6.176e-02 2.485e-01
#  subject.2 B           0.000e+00 0.000e+00
#  subject.3 C           6.979e-02 2.642e-01
#  subject.4 A:B         1.549e-16 1.245e-08
#  subject.5 A:C         4.566e-03 6.757e-02
#  subject.6 B:C         0.000e+00 0.000e+00
#  Residual              6.587e-01 8.116e-01
# Number of obs: 96, groups:  subject, 12
```

Now we can see what is pathological about the original example. The best-fitting model is one that implies that several of the random variance components are negative. But `lmer()` (and most other mixed model programs) constrains the estimates of variance components to be non-negative. This is generally considered a sensible constraint, since variances can of course never truly be negative. However, a consequence of this constraint is that mixed models are unable to accurately represent datasets that feature negative intraclass correlations, that is, datasets where observations from the same cluster are *less* (rather than more) similar on average than observations drawn randomly from the dataset, and consequently where within-cluster variance substantially exceeds between-cluster variance. Such datasets are perfectly reasonable datasets that one will occasionally come across in the real world (or accidentally simulate!), but they cannot be sensibly described by a variance-components model, because they imply negative variance components. They can however be "non-sensibly" described by such models, *if* the software will allow it. `aov()` allows it. `lmer()` does not.

Comment: +1. Re `I am not sure why these two methods give different results, as again I think they are "in principle" equivalent, but maybe it is for some numerical/computational reasons` - do you perhaps understand this better now (two years later)? I tried to figure out what is the difference, but don't get it either...

Comment: @amoeba My current thinking is still pretty much the same as then: AFAIK, the two models are statistically equivalent (in the sense that they make the same predictions about the data and imply the same standard errors), even though the random effects are parameterized differently. I think the observed differences -- which seem to only occur sometimes -- are just due to computational issues. In particular, I suspect that you could fiddle around with optimizer settings (like varying starting points or using more strict convergence criteria) until the two models returned exactly the same answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am rather unconvinced: I tried to fiddle with optimizer settings and could not change anything in the outcomes; my impression is that both models are well converged. I might ask this is a separate question at some moment.

Comment: I keep investigating this issue and realized the following: as soon as repeated-measures factors have more than two levels, these two methods become entirely different! If `A` has $k$ levels then `(1|A:sub)` estimates only one variance parameter, whereas `(0+A|sub)` estimates $k-1$ variance parameters and $k(k-1)/2$ correlations between them. My understanding is that classical ANOVA estimates only one variance parameter and so should be equivalent to the first method, not the second. Right? But for $k=2$ both methods estimate one parameter, and I am still not quite sure why they disagree.

Comment: Getting back to this issue... I noticed that for the two-factor case where two `lmer` calls produce identical `anova()` output, the random effect variances are nevertheless quite different: see `VarCorr(mod1)` and `VarCorr(mod2)`. I don't quite understand why this happens; do you? For `mod3` and `mod4`, one can see that four out of seven variances for `mod3` are actually equal to zero (for `mod4` all seven are non-zero); this "singularity" in `mod3` is probably why the anova tables differ. Apart from that, how would you use your "preferred way" if `a` and `b` had more than two levels?

Comment: @amoeba The variances differ because the random effects are parameterized differently. In `mod2` and `mod4` they are parameterized the same way as the fixed effects: in terms of intercepts (=group means) and slopes (=group differences (divided by 2)). In `mod1` and `mod3` they are parameterized in terms of intercepts and *cell means*; i.e. (for $n$ subjects) the means of the $2n$ `a` cells (collapsing over `b`) and the $2n$ `b` cells (collapsing over `a`). Finally, if `a` or `b` had $k>2$ levels, I would manually replace them with $k-1$ numeric columns of the desired contrast codes.

Comment: @amoeba That's a good insight about the zero random effect variances in `mod3` vs. `mod4`. I agree that's probably finally the source of the difference in log-likelihoods! Perhaps in an unconstrained optimization that allowed negative variance components the two models would always return equivalent results, but in the constrained optimization of `lme4` where variance components must be non-negative, different (but theoretically statistically equivalent) parameterizations can return different results when one of the parameterizations bumps into the zero boundary.

Comment: I am still not quite sure about the case when e.g. `a` has $k=3$ levels. Then instead of your numeric variable `A`, you would have `A1` and `A2`. How would you modify the `(0+A|subject)` term then, given that it should (?) still have only 1 variance parameter in order to correspond to the `(1|a:subject)` term which in turn corresponds to the classical RM-ANOVA's `Error(a:subject)` term? And regarding two variance parametrizations... hmm, I have to think about it. I don't get why it's `mod2/4` variances that match `EMS()` output when it's `mod1/3` that mimic `Error()` structure from `aov`.

Comment: @amoebasaysReinstateMonica I think models like `mod1` and `mod3` are forced to estimate some of the variance components as zero in some situations. Consider a simpler data set with only two conditions `set.seed(123); d <- MASS::mvrnorm(100, c(0, 10), cbind(c(1, -0.5), c(-0.5, 1))); d <- data.frame(y = rep(c(d[, 1], d[, 2]), 4) + rnorm(400), c = rep(rep(c(-1, 1), each = 100), 4), subj = gl(100, 1, 400)); d$f <-factor(d$c)` where the 1st and the 2nd condition are negatively correlated.  We define `m1 <- lmer(y ~ f + (1|subj) + (0 + c|subj), d)` and `m2 <- lmer(y ~ f + (1|subj) + (1|subj:f), d)`.

Comment: @amoebasaysReinstateMonica (continued) The subject's intercept variance in `m2` is estimated as zero and `m1` fits the data better than `m2` (log-likelihoods -1182.1 vs. -1187.7). For `m2`, this is the covariance matrix of the random vector for a subject in the two conditions: $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma^2_1 +\sigma^2_2 & \sigma^2_1\\ \sigma^2_1 & \sigma^2_1 + \sigma^2_2 \end{bmatrix}$ where $\sigma^2_1$ and $\sigma^2_2$ are the variance parameters for the participant and the participant-condition-combination intercepts, respectively.

Comment: @amoebasaysReinstateMonica (continued) Because variance components are constrained to be non-negative in the optimization of `lme4`, $\sigma^2_1$, which represents the covariance of a subject in the 1st and 2nd condition (which is negative in our data),  has to be estimated as zero. This is not the case for `m1` where $\Sigma$ looks like this $\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2&\sigma^2_1-\sigma^2_2\\\sigma^2_1-\sigma^2_2&\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2\end{bmatrix}$ (given the sum-coding) where $\sigma^2_1$ and $\sigma^2_2$ are the variance parameters for the intercept and the contrast, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Are `a`, `b`, `c` fixed or random effects? If they are fixed, your syntax will simply be

```
summary(aov(y~a*b*c+Error(subject), d))
Error: subject
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 11  13.47   1.225               

Error: Within
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
a          1   1.41   1.408   1.730 0.19235   
b          1   3.12   3.118   3.829 0.05399 . 
c          1   6.38   6.381   7.836 0.00647 **
a:b        1   1.57   1.571   1.929 0.16889   
a:c        1   1.09   1.091   1.339 0.25072   
b:c        1   1.41   1.413   1.735 0.19168   
a:b:c      1   0.10   0.101   0.124 0.72518   
Residuals 77  62.70   0.814  

library(lmerTest)
anova(lmer(y ~ a*b*c+(1|subject), data=d))
Analysis of Variance Table of type 3  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
      Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F.value   Pr(>F)   
a     1.4085  1.4085     1 76.991  1.7297 0.192349   
b     3.1180  3.1180     1 76.991  3.8291 0.053995 . 
c     6.3809  6.3809     1 76.991  7.8363 0.006469 **
a:b   1.5706  1.5706     1 76.991  1.9289 0.168888   
a:c   1.0907  1.0907     1 76.991  1.3394 0.250716   
b:c   1.4128  1.4128     1 76.991  1.7350 0.191680   
a:b:c 0.1014  0.1014     1 76.991  0.1245 0.725183
```

Comment: They are fixed effects. However, the ANOVA model you fit is not the model that seems to be the classical repeated measures ANOVA model, see e.g., [here](http://www.personality-project.org/r/r.anova.html#withintwo). See the Error strata in your and my case.

Comment: Actually how they do it is incorrect. If you have a fully crossed factorial repeated measures design (or randomized block factorial design), you should get only 1 error term, aside from `subject`, for all effects (i.e., `Within`). See Experimental Design: Procedures for Behavioral Sciences (2013) by Kirk, chapter 10 (p.458) or my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694664/repeated-measures-within-subjects-anova-in-r/25206796#25206796)

Comment: Let's sidestep this question for the moment and assume that the model I fitted would be the correct model. How would you fit this using `lmer`? I will nevertheless get my copy of Kirk (2nd edition only) and see what it says.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you think of Kirk's chapter. I think the chapter number in the 2nd ed. is different. Meanwhile I'll try to fit different `lmer` models. The best way to check the model fit is to check their dfs using `lmerTest` because the K-R approximation is supposed to give you `exact` dfs and hence p-values.

Comment: Unfortunately I just moved cities and my Kirk is still in one of the moving boxes which I haven't yet opened (and are supposed to go to the uni) so it will take some time. However, the dfs are probably not the way to go. If you test those using my `afex::mixed` (which I obviously prefer) you will see that for the last `lmer` example they match the ANOVA. However, the F values are still different.

Comment: I have the 2nd edition of Kirk, where I believe the relevant discussion is on pp. 443-449, which discusses a two-way (not three-way) example. Expected mean squares, either assuming additivity of A and B or not, are given on p. 447. Assuming A and B are fixed and subjects/blocks are random, we can see from the expected mean squares listed by Kirk under "non-additive model" that tests of A, B, and AB each involve different error terms, namely, the relevant interactions with block/subject. The same principle extends to the present three-way example.

Comment: Given @JakeWestfall's last comment, this answer seems to be wrong, hence -1. I don't have access to Kirk's book and cannot double-check myself, but Masato's answer clearly contradicts the standard advice, see e.g. here http://dwoll.de/rexrepos/posts/anovaMixed.html.