# Different results obtained with lmer() and aov() for three-way repeated-measures experiment

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

My question concerns results from one of my experiments, where analyzing the data with RM-ANOVA (using either `ezANOVA` or `aov` on the aggregated data in R) yields significantly different results from fitting the equivalent model on the raw data in `lmer`.

In the experiment, participants are presented with 40 different items that they have to rate on attractiveness on a 200-point scale before a manipulation takes place, and afterwards (**DV**). The items are manipulated on two independent variables, both crossed within-subject:

**att_cond**: attentional cueing (factor; cued/uncued)

**gng_cond**: response (go/no-go) (factor; responded/unresponded)

In short, participants rate all the items on the 200-point scale, receive a training in which half of the items receive an attentional cue while the other half is uncued. Similarly, half of the items are responded to during the training (go-items), while the other half are non-responded items (no-go items).

Thus, my data has the following structure:

> `>head(subset_go_nogo[c(1:3, 4,5,7)])
>     subjectID FoodItem gng_cond att_cond timepoint rating
>   1         3       63       go        0         0     136
>   2         3       23    no-go        1         0     179
>   3         3       55    no-go        1         0     144
>   4         3        7       go        0         0     165
>   5         3       42    no-go        1         0     144
>   6         3       16    no-go        0         0     180`
>
> `>str(subset_go_nogo[c(1:3, 4,5,7)])
>   'data.frame':   3280 obs. of  6 variables:
>    $ subjectID: Factor w/ 41 levels "10","11","13",..: 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 ...
>    $ FoodItem : Factor w/ 80 levels "1","10","11",..: 60 16 51 67 37 8 13 19 61 32 ...
>    $ gng_cond : Factor w/ 2 levels "no-go","go": 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
>    $ att_cond : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
>    $ timepoint: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>    $ rating  : num  136 179 144 165 144 180 200 173 183 175 ...`

Therefore, I have 40 ratings per participant (N = 41). I am especially interested in the `timepoint*gng_cond*att_cond` 3-way interaction of which I have 10 observations per participant in each cell, without any missing data (e.g):

> `>with(subset_go_nogo, table(gng_cond, att_cond, timepoint, subjectID))`
>
> `, , timepoint = 0, subjectID = 10
>
>            att_cond
>   gng_cond  0  1
>      no-go 10 10
>      go    10 10`
>
> `, , timepoint = 1, subjectID = 10
>           att_cond
>   gng_cond  0  1
>      no-go 10 10
>      go    10 10`

I believe that my design is balanced and that I have crossed random effects of subjectID and `FoodItem`. However, to simplify the problem I will demonstrate what I get on the model with only `subjectID` as a random intercept.

**I will provide a lot of output in the following, but I will give a short summary of the main problem first**:
**In sum, while in the first models (random intercept ´lmer´ and ´subjectID`-only error term aov) the models yield identical results and p-values. However, when adding the error-terms of the within-subject predictors to the model, the anova yields a significant 3-way interaction with *F* = 6.446, *p* = 0.0151 while the mixed-effects model indicates a non-significant interaction of *F* = 3.629, *p* = 0.0568.**

If I start off by fitting the most basic version of the lmer model including the 3-way interaction I get:

`> lmer.1 <- lmer(rating ~ timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond + (1  | subjectID), data = d)`,

yielding the following model summary:

> summary(lmer.1)

```
Random effects:
  Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
subjectID (Intercept) 279.4    16.71   
Residual              922.1    30.37   
Number of obs: 3280, groups:  subjectID, 41

Fixed effects:
  Estimate Std. Error            df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     140.88293    2.66360   40.00000  52.892   <2e-16 ***
timepoint1                        6.92561    0.53021 3232.00000  13.062   <2e-16 ***
att_cond1                         0.13354    0.53021 3232.00000   0.252   0.8012    
gng_cond1                        -1.35854    0.53021 3232.00000  -2.562   0.0104 *  
timepoint1:att_cond1             -0.02744    0.53021 3232.00000  -0.052   0.9587    
timepoint1:gng_cond1              1.36220    0.53021 3232.00000   2.569   0.0102 *  
att_cond1:gng_cond1               1.00549    0.53021 3232.00000   1.896   0.0580 .  
timepoint1:att_cond1:gng_cond1   -0.98963    0.53021 3232.00000  -1.866   0.0621 .  
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and mean squares:

> `> anova(lmer.1)
>   Analysis of Variance Table
>                               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value
>   timepoint                    1 157322  157322 170.6164
>   att_cond                     1     58      58   0.0634
>   gng_cond                     1   6054    6054   6.5652
>   timepoint:att_cond           1      2       2   0.0027
>   timepoint:gng_cond           1   6086    6086   6.6006
>   att_cond:gng_cond            1   3316    3316   3.5963
>   timepoint:att_cond:gng_cond  1   3212    3212   3.4838`

The equivalent RM-ANOVA would be:

```
aov1 <- aov(rating ~ timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond + Error(subjectID),data=d_aggregated)
summary(aov1)

Error: subjectID
Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 40 930832   23271               

Error: Within
Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
timepoint                      1  157322  157322 170.616 <2e-16 ***
att_cond                       1      58      58   0.063 0.8012    
gng_cond                       1    6054    6054   6.565 0.0104 *  
timepoint:att_cond             1       2       2   0.003 0.9587    
timepoint:gng_cond             1    6086    6086   6.601 0.0102 *  
att_cond:gng_cond              1    3316    3316   3.596 0.0580 .  
timepoint:att_cond:gng_cond    1    3212    3212   3.484 0.0621 .  
Residuals                   3232 2980166     922                   
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So far so good, the models yield the exact same output (except for rounding deviation).

However, the matter becomes more complicated when I fit a model with a full random error structure, that is, a `lmer` model corresponding to the following `aov` specification:

```
aov2 <- aov(rating ~ timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond + Error(subjectID/(timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond)),data=d_aggregated)
summary(aov2)

Error: subjectID
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 40 930832   23271               

Error: subjectID:timepoint
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
timepoint  1 157322  157322   46.41 3.43e-08 ***
  Residuals 40 135601    3390                     
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subjectID:att_cond
Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
att_cond   1     58    58.5   0.125  0.725
Residuals 40  18675   466.9               

Error: subjectID:gng_cond
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)   
gng_cond   1   6054    6054    10.6 0.0023 **
  Residuals 40  22834     571                  
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subjectID:timepoint:att_cond
Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
timepoint:att_cond  1      2     2.5   0.006  0.941
Residuals          40  17716   442.9               

Error: subjectID:timepoint:gng_cond
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
timepoint:gng_cond  1   6086    6086   11.39 0.00165 **
  Residuals          40  21377     534                   
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subjectID:att_cond:gng_cond
                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
att_cond:gng_cond  1   3316    3316   6.328  0.016 *
  Residuals         40  20963     524                 
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subjectID:timepoint:att_cond:gng_cond
                              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
timepoint:att_cond:gng_cond  1   3212    3212   6.446 0.0151 *
  Residuals                   40  19934     498                 
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Within
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 2952 2723066   922.4
```

In my account the right `lmer` representation of this model would be:

```
lmer.2 <- lmer(rating ~ timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond + (1 
+ timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond| subjectID), data = d)
```

or after reading [THIS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122662/152063) answer to another post by Jake Westfall.

> `lmer.3 <- lmer(rating1 ~ timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond +(1|subjectID) + (0 + timepoint | subjectID) + (0 + att_cond | subjectID) 
>                + (0+gng_cond |subjectID) +  (0+timepoint:att_cond|subjectID) + 
>               (0+timepoint:gng_cond|subjectID) + (0 + 
>               att_cond:gng_cond|subjectID), d,
>                control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9)))`

giving:

```
Random effects:
Groups      Name                     Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr             
subjectID   (Intercept)              1.065e-07 3.263e-04                  
subjectID.1 timepoint0               0.000e+00 0.000e+00                  
timepoint1                           5.772e-09 7.598e-05  NaN             
subjectID.2 att_cond0                0.000e+00 0.000e+00                  
att_cond1                            6.738e-12 2.596e-06  NaN             
subjectID.3 gng_condno-go            0.000e+00 0.000e+00                  
gng_condgo                           2.876e-11 5.363e-06  NaN             
subjectID.4 timepoint0:att_cond0     1.028e+01 3.206e+00                  
timepoint1:att_cond0                 3.109e+01 5.576e+00 -1.00            
timepoint0:att_cond1                 9.653e+00 3.107e+00  1.00 -1.00      
timepoint1:att_cond1                 9.413e+01 9.702e+00 -1.00  1.00 -1.00
subjectID.5 timepoint0:gng_condno-go 8.150e+01 9.028e+00                  
timepoint1:gng_condno-go             8.642e+01 9.296e+00 1.00             
timepoint0:gng_condgo                8.465e+01 9.200e+00 1.00  1.00       
timepoint1:gng_condgo                2.007e+02 1.417e+01 1.00  1.00  1.00 
subjectID.6 att_cond0:gng_condno-go  1.672e+02 1.293e+01                  
att_cond1:gng_condno-go              1.266e+02 1.125e+01 1.00             
att_cond0:gng_condgo                 1.406e+02 1.186e+01 1.00  1.00       
att_cond1:gng_condgo                 1.840e+02 1.356e+01 1.00  1.00  1.00 
Residual                             8.850e+02 2.975e+01                  
Number of obs: 3280, groups:  subjectID, 41

Fixed effects:
Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     140.88293    2.60631   43.00000  54.054  < 2e-16 ***
timepoint1                        6.92561    1.01104   41.00000   6.850 2.75e-08 ***
att_cond1                         0.13354    0.54501  190.00000   0.245   0.8067    
gng_cond1                        -1.35854    0.55763  114.00000  -2.436   0.0164 *  
timepoint1:att_cond1             -0.02744    0.54272  207.00000  -0.051   0.9597    
timepoint1:gng_cond1              1.36220    0.55089  120.00000   2.473   0.0148 *  
att_cond1:gng_cond1               1.00549    0.53601  250.00000   1.876   0.0618 .  
timepoint1:att_cond1:gng_cond1   -0.98963    0.51944 3171.00000  -1.905   0.0568 .  
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, as mentioned in both cases I get vastly different results for aov vs. lmer.

My questions regarding this rather long post would be:

**1)** Why and how do the estimates differ?

**2)** Is there any situation in which a RM-anova might actually be preferable, as it yields significant effects in this case while the mixed-model does not, or is this due to mis-specification or Type-1 error?

**3)** Does the model I was using previously, `lmer.2 <- lmer(rating ~ timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond + (1 + timepoint*att_cond*gng_cond| subjectID), data = d)`, make sense given the data, or should the random structure not include the 3-way interaction (i.e. lmer.3 above).

**EDIT**

after feeback from user amoeba, I coded the contrasts manually following advice from Jake Westfall in the post linked above and included a 3-way random term in lmer.2 and lmer.3, i.e:

```
lmer.2 <- lmer(rating ~ timepoint_n*att_cond_n*gng_cond_n + (1 +  
timepoint_n*att_cond_n*gng_cond_n || subjectID), data = d)
```

and

```
lmer.3 <- lmer(rating ~ timepoint_n*att_cond_n*gng_cond_n +(1|subjectID) + 
(0 + timepoint_n | subjectID) + (0 + att_cond_n | subjectID) + (0+gng_cond_n 
|subjectID) +  (0+timepoint_n:att_cond_n|subjectID) +
(0+timepoint_n:gng_cond_n|subjectID) + 
(0 + att_cond_n:gng_cond_n|subjectID) +                                         
(0 + att_cond_n:gng_cond_n:timepoint_n|subjectID), data = d)
```

with manual coding of numeric -1 and 1 for each factor. The outcome of both 
model specifications for `lmer` is identical so i only provide lmer.3. However, it is still quite different from what I get from aov (see above).

```
> summary(lmer.3)
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom ['lmerMod']
Formula: rating ~ timepoint_n * att_cond_n * gng_cond_n + (1 | subjectID) +  
  (0 + timepoint_n | subjectID) + (0 + att_cond_n | subjectID) +  
  (0 + gng_cond_n | subjectID) + (0 + timepoint_n:att_cond_n |  
                                    subjectID) + (0 + timepoint_n:gng_cond_n | subjectID) + (0 +  
                                                                                               att_cond_n:gng_cond_n | subjectID) + (0 + att_cond_n:gng_cond_n:timepoint_n |      subjectID)
Data: d
Control: lmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+09))

REML criterion at convergence: 31759.4

Scaled residuals: 
  Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0614 -0.5976 -0.0071  0.6375  3.8063 

Random effects:
  Groups      Name                              Variance Std.Dev.
subjectID   (Intercept)                       279.75   16.726  
subjectID.1 timepoint_n                        31.24    5.589  
subjectID.2 att_cond_n                          0.00    0.000  
subjectID.3 gng_cond_n                          0.00    0.000  
subjectID.4 timepoint_n:att_cond_n              0.00    0.000  
subjectID.5 timepoint_n:gng_cond_n              0.00    0.000  
subjectID.6 att_cond_n:gng_cond_n               0.00    0.000  
subjectID.7 att_cond_n:gng_cond_n:timepoint_n   0.00    0.000  
Residual                                      891.15   29.852  
Number of obs: 3280, groups:  subjectID, 41

Fixed effects:
  Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                        140.88293    2.66360   40.00000  52.892  < 2e-16 ***
timepoint_n                         -6.92561    1.01664   40.00000  -6.812 3.43e-08 ***
att_cond_n                          -0.13354    0.52124 3192.00000  -0.256  0.79782    
gng_cond_n                           1.35854    0.52124 3192.00000   2.606  0.00919 ** 
timepoint_n:att_cond_n              -0.02744    0.52124 3192.00000  -0.053  0.95802    
timepoint_n:gng_cond_n               1.36220    0.52124 3192.00000   2.613  0.00901 ** 
att_cond_n:gng_cond_n                1.00549    0.52124 3192.00000   1.929  0.05382 .  
timepoint_n:att_cond_n:gng_cond_n    0.98963    0.52124 3192.00000   1.899  0.05771 .  
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
  (Intr) tmpnt_ att_c_ gng_c_ tmpnt_n:t__ tmpnt_n:g__ a__:__
timepoint_n 0.000                                                     
att_cond_n  0.000  0.000                                              
gng_cond_n  0.000  0.000  0.000                                       
tmpnt_n:t__ 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000                                
tmpnt_n:g__ 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000                         
att_cnd_:__ 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000       0.000             
tmpn_:__:__ 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000       0.000       0.000
```

Comment: (0) If you read Jake's answer on reproducing three-way RM ANOVA in lmer (and discussion in the comments underneath), you saw that it's quite tricky to specify this correctly. Jake is an expert and still he does not fully understand why one parametrization work and another one does not. So just keep in mind this is very tricky stuff.

Comment: (1a) You don't show output of lmer.2, only of lmer.3. (1b) lmer.3 is not quite what Jake recommends. Re-read his answer. He uses this approach with variables A,B,C manually coded as +1 and -1, not with default R factors. You get some +1 and -1 correlations in the output of lmer.3 whereas there should not be any correlations at all, indicating that you are specifying this model wrong. (1c) You'll need to include three-way interaction into lmer.3 as well, because you have 10 measurements per three-way factor combination.

Comment: (2) RM-ANOVA can be preferable because you don't need to worry that you specified something incorrectly. You have fully balanced design, which is precisely the case for which RM-ANOVA is designed. However, with RM-ANOVA you will not be able to include a crossed random effect of Item. This is a big drawback.

Comment: (3) Yes, lmer.2 makes sense, the three-way interaction *should* be there in your case. Try replacing `|` with `||` to prevent lmer from estimating correlations between terms.

Comment: @amoeba thank you for the help! **0/2** yes, but which model should be "trusted"/used if they tend to disagree about an effects' significance; the RM-anova, the mixed-model (including the crossed-item random term) or both? **1a/3** lmer.2 and lmer.3 are very similar but lmer.2 had convergence issues (that were solved by manual contrast coding now) the correlations are also avoided that way. In my experience, excludig random correlations for R factor-objects can be tricky.

Comment: I think classical ANOVA can be trusted whenever it is appropriate, meaning whenever you have a fully balanced design with a single random effect. In this case, in general, mixed model output should agree with it, but in practice it is sometimes difficult to achieve (as you see). In your particular case, I suggest you modify your lmer.3 model to follow Jake's manual coding, include a three-way interaction, and if it still does not agree with ANOVA, edit your question to include this update model and output (perhaps also for lmer.2).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looking at the output of your updated lmer model, one can see that lots of random effects have 0 variance. This can either be due to some weird (potentially convergence-related?) issues that Jake and me were discussing in the comments under his answer, or due to the fact that RM-ANOVA estimates are actually negative and lmer cannot reproduce them -- see last paragraph of Jake's answer (and also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122717, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14088, etc). You could check this second hypothesis by running Jake's `EMS` function.

Comment: (1/2) Thanks again. I tried the EMS function and get                      
   ` s                    69.838600
    tp:s                7.711213
    att:s              -1.423696
    gng:s            -1.098723
    tp:att:s          -1.498620
    tp:gng:s        -1.212590
    att:gng:s       -1.244919
    tp:att:gng:s   -2.650683
    e                   922.447967`                                                                                               So your 2nd hypothesis seems to be correct, of lmer being restricted to positive variance components.

Comment: (2/2) thus, the models still disagree when I use the non-aggregated data. However ,when I run `lmer`on the aggregated data (excluding the random 3-way interaction that is confounded with residual variance in that case) the models (lmer and aov) yield the exact same results. I wonder what your opinion is on what model makes more sense _theoretically_ as of course, the variance is not negative in reality. It seems to me that the positivity restriction on random variance from the lme still makes sense, even if aov - the linear model might achieve a better, but non-sensible, fit.

Comment: I did not realize that you ran all anovas on aggregated data; I think you should be able to run `aov` with raw data as well. It would be interesting to do so and to look at the p-value for the 3-way interaction. But this is a bit of an aside. Your main question is tricky: real variance can indeed not be negative, but if one wants to have unbiased estimate of variance one has to allow negative estimates (otherwise there will always be a positive bias for variance=0)... So one can say something in favor of both options. [cont]

Comment: [cont.] HOWEVER, don't you want to include random effect of `Item`? If so, you *need* non-aggregated data and you  *need* lmer... And you really should include this random effect, because it's known that omitting random effect of item can bias everything else and can easily increase false positive rate beyond the nominal alpha level. So I would say now that we understand what the discrepancy is due to, you can proceed to the lmer with crossed random effects.

Comment: I did not mention it but I ran the anova on aggregated and non-aggregated data with identical results except for all Mean-Squares being multiplied by 10 (which makes sense intuitively?) Thank you for the very helpful advice, I indeed want to include the random terms for items and will proceed as you said.

Comment: Yes, this indeed makes sense, I should have realized that :) Consider posting your Update as an Answer and marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jake Westfall's `EMS`function documented [HERE](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/18603-Share-your-functions-amp-code?p=82050&viewfull=1#post82050), I estimated the variance components from the mixed model. The random variances above that were estimated to be 0 are indeed negative as derived by EMS.

```
cbind(rev(ans[c(grep("e",names(ans)),grep("s",names(ans)))])/
    c(1,2,2,2,4,4,4,5,1))


s        69.838600
a:s       7.711213
b:s      -1.423696
c:s      -1.098723
a:b:s    -1.498620
a:c:s    -1.212590
b:c:s    -1.244919
a:b:c:s  -2.650683
e       922.447967
```

When running `lmer.4` on the aggregated data-set, `lmer`gives identical results (except for the 3-way interaction, but it is still very similar).

```
> lmer.4 <- lmer(rating ~ timepoint_n*att_cond_n*gng_cond_n +(1|subjectID) + (0 + timepoint_n | subjectID) 
                                  (0 + att_cond_n | subjectID) + (0+gng_cond_n |subjectID) +  (0+timepoint_n:att_cond_n|subjectID) + 
                                  (0+timepoint_n:gng_cond_n|subjectID) + (0 + att_cond_n:gng_cond_n|subjectID), 
                                 data = d_aggr, control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9)))
> summary(lmer.4)
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom ['lmerMod']
Formula: rating ~ timepoint_n * att_cond_n * gng_cond_n + (1 | subjectID) +  
  (0 + timepoint_n | subjectID) + (0 + att_cond_n | subjectID) +  
  (0 + gng_cond_n | subjectID) + (0 + timepoint_n:att_cond_n |  
                                    subjectID) + (0 + timepoint_n:gng_cond_n | subjectID) + (0 +      att_cond_n:gng_cond_n | subjectID)
Data: d_aggr
Control: lmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+09))

REML criterion at convergence: 2438.7

Scaled residuals: 
  Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0726 -0.1788 -0.0138  0.2457  4.3407 

Random effects:
  Groups      Name                   Variance  Std.Dev. 
subjectID   (Intercept)            2.850e+02 1.688e+01
subjectID.1 timepoint_n            3.651e+01 6.042e+00
subjectID.2 att_cond_n             2.257e-11 4.750e-06
subjectID.3 gng_cond_n             1.269e+00 1.126e+00
subjectID.4 timepoint_n:att_cond_n 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
subjectID.5 timepoint_n:gng_cond_n 8.132e-01 9.018e-01
subjectID.6 att_cond_n:gng_cond_n  6.839e-01 8.270e-01
Residual                           4.694e+01 6.851e+00
Number of obs: 328, groups:  subjectID, 41

Fixed effects:
                                   Estimate   Std. Error      df  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                       140.88293    2.66360  40.00000  52.892  < 2e-16 ***
timepoint_n                        -6.92561    1.01664  40.00000  -6.812 3.43e-08 ***
att_cond_n                         -0.13354    0.37828 120.00000  -0.353  0.72470    
gng_cond_n                          1.35854    0.41718  40.00000   3.256  0.00230 ** 
timepoint_n:att_cond_n             -0.02744    0.37828 120.00000  -0.073  0.94230    
timepoint_n:gng_cond_n              1.36220    0.40365  40.00000   3.375  0.00165 ** 
att_cond_n:gng_cond_n               1.00549    0.39972  40.00000   2.515  0.01601 *  
timepoint_n:att_cond_n:gng_cond_n   0.98963    0.37828 120.00000   2.616  0.01004 *  
  ---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
(Intr) tmpnt_ att_c_ gng_c_ tmpnt_n:t__ tmpnt_n:g__ a__:__
timepoint_n 0.000                                                     
att_cond_n  0.000  0.000                                              
gng_cond_n  0.000  0.000  0.000                                       
tmpnt_n:t__ 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000                                
tmpnt_n:g__ 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000                         
att_cnd_:__ 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000       0.000             
tmpn_:__:__ 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000       0.000       0.000
```

Therefore, it seems that as `lmer` cannot achieve the fit of `aov` by not being able/allowed to estimate negative variance components, the results differ, while the difference is gone when running the `lmer` representation of the model on the aggregated data, eliminating the negatively estimated variance components.