# 3-way repeated measures ANOVA with nlme::lme assuming compound symmetry

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

For teaching purposes I want to show the similarity between a 3-way repeated measures ANOVA `aov(y ~ A*B*C + Error(Subject/(A*B*C)), data)` and the corresponding lmm assuming compound symmetry in R.

From [this response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122662/136579) I found out that the corresponding `lme4::lmer` model is

```
lmer(y ~ A*B*C + (1|Subject) + (1|A:Subject) + (1|B:Subject) + (1|C:Subject) 
               + (1|A:B:Subject) + (1|A:C:Subject) + (1|B:C:Subject), data))
```

How can I fit this model with `nlme::lme` assuming compound symmetry?