# Post hoc test after ANOVA with repeated measures using R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, post-hoc, contrasts

I have performed a repeated measures ANOVA in R, as follows:

```
aov_velocity = aov(Velocity ~ Material + Error(Subject/(Material)), data=scrd)
summary(aov_velocity)
```

- What syntax in R can be used to perform a post hoc test after an ANOVA with repeated measures?
- Would Tukey's test with Bonferroni correction be appropriate? If so, how could this be done in R?

Comment: see this related question on post hoc tests for repeated measures designs http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575/post-hocs-for-within-subjects-tests

Comment: About your 2nd point: [Tukey's HSD](http://bit.ly/oxasU8) already includes a "correction" for multiplicity (at the level of the test statistic, not the alpha level like in Bonferroni's method). So, there's no need to combine both.

Comment: @chl: so we don't need to correct the alpha level during the multiple pairwise comparisons in the case of Tukey's HSD ?

Comment: @stan No. (Note: Unplanned (post-hoc) tests should be performed after the ANOVA showed a significant result, especially if it concerns a confirmatory approach.)

Comment: I cannot find the data scrd to run the example

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you could do is specify the model with `lme` and then use `glht` from the `multcomp` package to do what you want. However, lme gives slightly different F-values than a standard ANOVA (see also my recent [questions here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14088/442)).

```
lme_velocity = lme(Velocity ~ Material, data=scrd, random = ~1|Subject)
anova(lme_velocity)

require(multcomp)
summary(glht(lme_velocity, linfct=mcp(Material = "Tukey")), test = adjusted(type = "bonferroni"))
```

For other contrasts then bonferroni, see e.g., [the book on `multcomp` from the authors of the package](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584885742).

You may also want to see [this post on the R-mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/163433.html), and [this blog post for specifying a repeated measures ANOVA in R](http://blog.gribblelab.org/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/).

However, as [shown in this question from me](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14088/442) I am not sure if this approachs is identical to an ANOVA. Furthermore, glht only reports *z*-values instead of the usual *t* or *F* values. This seems to be uncommon, too.

So far, I haven't encountered another way of doing this.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stick with the `aov()` function you can use the `emmeans` package which can handle `aovlist` (and [many other](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html)) objects.

```
library("emmeans")
# set orthogonal contrasts
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))

aov_velocity <- aov(Velocity ~ Material + Error(Subject / Material), data = scrd)
```

After creating an `emmGrid` object as follows

```
emm <- emmeans(aov_velocity, ~ Material)
```

it is very easy to get all (post hoc) pairwise comparisons using the `pairs()` function or any desired contrast using the `contrast()` function of the `emmeans` package. Multiple-testing adjustments can be achieved via the `adjust` argument of these functions:

```
pairs(emm)  # adjust argument not specified -> default p-value adjustment in this case is "tukey"
```

For more information on this I found the detailed [emmeans vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/) and the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/emmeans.pdf) to be very helpful.

Also, you can find a complete (reproducible) example including a description on how to get the correct contrast weights in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54015241/8905144).

Note, however, that using a univariate model for the post hoc tests can result in anti-conservative *p*-values if sphericity is violated.

Answer (score -4):

If sphericity is met then you can run a two-way ANOVA:

```
aov_velocity = aov(Velocity~Material+Subject, data=scrd)
posthoc      = TukeyHSD(aov_velocity, 'Material', conf.level=0.95).
```