# Repeated-Measures ANOVA: how to locate the significant difference(s) by R?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I am trying to use `R` to run Repeated-Measures ANOVA. Based on the data from:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPB3xrsFl4o&list=PL568547ACA9211CCA&index=75

[image]

The inputs in `R` are:

```
anxiety = c(9,8,7,8,8,9,8,7,6,6,7,8,7,6,4,3,2,3,4,3,2) 
time = c(rep("Before",7), rep("Week_1",7), rep("Week_2",7)) 
person = c(rep(c("Person_1","Person_2","Person_3","Person_4","Person_5","Person_6","Person_7"),3))
anxiety_data = data.frame(person, anxiety, time)
```

I think I should use `aov()` function in this way:

```
Repeated_Measures_ANOVA = aov(anxiety ~ time + Error(person/time), data=anxiety_data)
```

Can I ask if the code is correct?

As the `TukeyHSD()` function could not work

```
> TukeyHSD(Repeated_Measures_ANOVA, conf.level = 0.95)
Error in UseMethod("TukeyHSD") : 
no applicable method for 'TukeyHSD' applied to an object of class "c('aovlist', 'listof')"
```

can I ask how to determine where the significant difference is if positive result is obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you use the `Error()` function within `aov()`, the resulting object is of class `'aovlist'` and `'listof'`:

```
> class(Repeated_Measures_ANOVA)
[1] "aovlist" "listof"
```

See also `?aov` under 'Details' and 'Value'

`TukeyHSD()` requires an object of class `'aov'` in order to work (see `?TukeyHSD`).

One way to navigate around this problem is to use a linear mixed-effects model. There are two main options. The one I show here uses the `lmer()` function from the `lme4` package. Check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/post-hoc-test-after-anova-with-repeated-measures-using-r) for a different way using the `lme()` function and `ghlt()` function from the `multcomp` package to get Tukey adjusted multiple mean comparisons.

```
require(lme4)
lmer.fit <- lmer(anxiety ~ time + (1|person), data = anxiety_data)
summary(lmer.fit)
```

To get *p-values* for your fixed effect `time` you could use the `mixed` function from the `afex` package (make sure to check `?mixed` so that you know what the options are!)

```
require(afex)
mixed(anxiety ~ time + (1|person), data = anxiety_data)
```

Then for Tukey adjusted multiple mean comparisons, you could use the `lsmeans` package:

```
require(lsmeans)
lsmeans(lmer.fit, pairwise~time, adjust="tukey")
```