# Within-subjects ANOVA with lme and multiple fixed variables

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I am looking at the relationship between age and DNA methylation in teeth samples. We collected three tissues from every tooth (dentin, cementum and pulp), but were unable to get measurements from every sample as you can see in the dataset below. The "Sample" variable contains the numbers of the teeth and "Tissue" represents the repeated measures. "ED1" is the response variable.

```
Sample   Tissue    Tooth Condition    Sex      Age   ED1
   <fctr>   <fctr>   <fctr>    <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1   Dentin Bicuspid    Intact      F 15.44422    53
 2      1     Pulp Bicuspid    Intact      F 15.44422    53
 3      2   Dentin Bicuspid    Intact      F 15.45243    56
 4      2     Pulp Bicuspid    Intact      F 15.45243    64
 5      3   Dentin    Molar    Intact      F 28.04928    50
 6      3     Pulp    Molar    Intact      F 28.04928    52
 7      4 Cementum Bicuspid    Intact      M 30.08077    26
 8      4   Dentin Bicuspid    Intact      M 30.08077    64
 9      4     Pulp Bicuspid    Intact      M 30.08077    70
10      5 Cementum    Molar    Intact      M 32.89528    34
# ... with 93 more rows
```

I wanted to test whether the collected tissue has a significant effect on the methylation measurements. A lot of googling led me to the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/post-hoc-test-after-anova-with-repeated-measures-using-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), and constructed my code similarly:

```
model1 <- lme(ED1 ~ Tissue, data = ANOVA_All, random = ~1|Sample)
```

But then I realised that I should also include age in this model, so I did. And then I added Tissue in the last argument to make it clear that Tissue is in fact the repeated measure within Sample, and Age is just a fixed effect:

```
model2 <- lme(ED1 ~ Age + Tissue, data = ANOVA_All, random = ~Tissue|Sample)

> anova(model2)
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    51 2110.2166  <.0001
Age             1    48   12.8560   8e-04
Tissue          2    48   87.7027  <.0001
```

So **my first question** would be whether this is the correct way to go about that. Changing the "random" argument like that was somewhat of a guess, I am quite bad with constructing syntax so any feedback is very welcome.

We also collected data on sex, type of tooth and condition of the tooth and I would like to include these as well, so I simply expanded the function:

```
model3 <- lme(ED1 ~ Age + Tissue + Sex + Tooth + Condition, data = ANOVA_All, random = ~Tissue|Sample)

> anova(model3)
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    48 2324.9223  <.0001
Age             1    48   12.4313  0.0009
Tissue          2    48   89.3566  <.0001
Sex             1    44    0.0383  0.8458
Tooth           3    44    1.2044  0.3193
Condition       3    44    2.3711  0.0833
```

But then I noticed that when I switch around the variables, the p-values change, to an extent where an insignificant effect can become significant. In the following model I moved Sex in front of Tissue, and it's p-value became significant:

```
model4 <- lme(ED1 ~ Age + Sex + Tissue + Tooth + Condition, data = ANOVA_All, random = ~Tissue|Sample)

> anova(model4)
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    48 2324.9229  <.0001
Age             1    48   12.4315  0.0009
Sex             1    44    5.0581  0.0296
Tissue          2    48   86.8457  <.0001
Tooth           3    44    1.2044  0.3193
Condition       3    44    2.3710  0.0833
```

So my **second question** is if someone could explain to me (in simple terms, preferably) why this happens? Is it because terms are added sequentially and moving Sex to the front allows it to "take credit" for a larger portion of the variance? And considering this, how can I know for sure whether a variable has a significant effect on ED1 or not?

My understanding of statistics and R is *very* limited and I realize I am trying to do things that are actually going way over my head. But I would greatly appreciate some answers that are not clouded with too many details so even I can understand and implement them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you seem to be mixing up age as a categorical variable eg. 1or zero.

Comment: How did you compute df - num and den for age (see model 12). what does Sample  - 1, 2, ...  represent ?

Comment: which meadurements and how many are missing ?

Comment: From your hypothesis it appears that you imtend to check whether there is significant difference in mythelation across types of tissue ? I have tried to restate your hypothesis. is that you have in mind