# R Mixed-Effect Models for 2-way Repeated Measures Design with more than 2-levels in each factor

Tags: r, multiple-regression, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, post-hoc

**Background:** I am running an experiment with the following parameters.

1. **Design:** 2-way Repeated Measures Design (as of right now there are *NO* between-group/grouping variables
2. **Dependent Variable:** A Rating of the likelihood of being shocked on a scale 1-100 (continuous variable) which I will call ***SEperSECpersub*** 9sorry for the crap name)
3. **Independent Variable 1:** A conditioned stimulus factor with 3 levels - CS-, CS+, CST - which I will call ***CS***
4. **Independent Variable 2:** A time variable representing the number of seconds after the onset of the CS from 1-12 which I will call ***sec***. I am currently considering this a continuous variable.

My data looks as follows:

`subject  CS sec SEperSECpersub
1    S03V1 CS-   1      80.166667
2    S03V1 CS-   2      76.541667
3    S03V1 CS-   3      53.166667
4    S03V1 CS-   4      26.291667
5    S03V1 CS-   5       9.708333
6    S03V1 CS-   6       8.416667
7    S03V1 CS-   7       7.500000
8    S03V1 CS-   8       7.416667
9    S03V1 CS-   9       7.500000
10   S03V1 CS-  10       6.875000
11   S03V1 CS-  11       7.166667
12   S03V1 CS-  12       6.833333
13   S03V1 CS+   1      52.791667
14   S03V1 CS+   2      53.333333
15   S03V1 CS+   3      68.791667`

**Problem:** Normally I would perform a repeated measures ANOVA to get at the effects of both **CS** and **sec** on **SEperSECpersub** but the more I'm reading the more online resources are directing similar questions to perform mixed models, which is what I am attempting to do now with R's `lmer` function. As I am new to mixed modeling AND R I am running into some issues in understanding model logic as well as syntax and my main issue with online tutorials is that they are primarily for experiments with 2-level factors or one-way ANOVAs - I do not think I have found any tutorials for higher level designs like this as "technically" this analysis is looking at a 3x12 (ugh) RM ANOVA. Given these pieces of information I have a series of questions.

**Main Question:** How can I use linear mixed modeling with the `lmer` function to do what a 2-way RM ANOVA would do so that I can find the effects of each variable/interaction and, more specifically, find WHICH time points differ significantly between CSs (specifically between the CS+ and CST) without having to perform 12-follow-up t-tests with corrections?

**My Steps/Thoughts so Far:**

1. While it may seem odd to include **sec** as a fixed effect, our hypotheses are about how the subjects time their responses and thus the difference between ratings during each second is important to us and will be considered a fixed variable. As I am used to ANOVAs I'm not sure how to structure the error term in this model. I assume there will be both a random intercept and slope for each both **CS** and **sec**. However, as time is inherent in experiencing any stimulus, each subject experiences each `CS` multiple times and each `sec` multiple times and each `sec` is experienced during each `CS` for each `subject`. Having read I believe this counts as 'completely crossed random effects'. Thus, would the model look as follows:

`model <- lme4(SEperSECpersub ~ CS * sec + (CS|subject) + (sec|subject)`.

2. Let's say the model is significant - what are the equivalent of 'follow-up tests' for situations with 2 variables and more than 2 levels per variable? I have seen websites that say to perform multiple models, adding one factor per model, and then run an anova on them to see if each variable contributes something 'significant. I have also seen certain posts say to use [multcomp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/post-hoc-test-after-anova-with-repeated-measures-using-r) although users seem unsatisfied with this route.

Ultimately I'm not sure what I can do here that would give me the answers I'm looking for. As stated before, although I am trying to see the effects of all variables and their interactions, the main reason I was looking at this direction is to identify at which seconds the CS ratings differ.