# Post Hoc comparisons, Two way repeated measures Anova

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, post-hoc

I run a two-way repeated measures anova in R:

```
a<-aov(acc~sound*cnd + Error(sbj/(sound + cnd)), data=d)
```

I regressed accuracy (of participants, sbj) on cnd (condition, having two levels: abstract vs. environmental), and sound (having four levels: 1st,2nd,3rd,4th).
There is an interaction, so I analysed data from each condition separately.
Results were similar in both conditions: There was an effect of sound, and post-hoc comparisons (following [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/post-hoc-test-after-anova-with-repeated-measures-using-r)) suggested these differences : (1st)>(4th)> (2nd or 3rd), for both conditions, as can also be seen on the graph below:
[image]

But the interesting part in my results is the interaction.

My question is how can I compare the differences between conditions at each level of sound.

I have already used package emmeans, so I managed to see that the difference is significant for each level of sound.

```
m<-emmeans(a, ~cnd|sound)
pairs(m)
```

But this not what I am looking for. I need to conduct multiple comparisons on the differences between means.
To be more clear(please see the image), I need to check if a and d are greater to b and c.

Any ideas?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Fotis

Comment: You need a contrast of contrasts. so save the first set of contrasts and contrast them: `con <- pairs(m); contrast(con, list(ab.vs.cd = c(1,1,-1,-1)/2), by = NULL)`

Comment: Thanks Russ. But I need to do _all six comparisons_, namely: a vs, b, a vs. c, a vs. d,  b vs. c, b vs. d, c vs. d. Not just compare a+d vs. c+d (I should have been more clear). Any thoughts?

Comment: That isn't what you asked, but it's even easier: `pairs(con, by = NULL)`. Or `contrast(m, interaction ="pairwise", by =NULL)`. This stuff is all pretty well documented. Please read the vignetter on interactions.

Comment: Russ, thank you so much for the response, that was exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate your advice! (And I will read the vignetter you suggested). Regards

Comment: One more question please, regarding multiplicity adjustments. I need to do another post-hoc test. Namely, I need to check if consecutive differences between sounds are different among conditions. So, I first calculated differences for each conditions, `m2<-emmeans(a, ~sound|cnd)`, and then consecutive contrasts, `con2<-contrast(m2, "consec")`. Now, what I finally need are these comparisons:  `pairs(con2, by="contrast")`. But the output suggests that these are 3 independent tests. Right? Any way that the 3 comparisons are adjusted for multiplicity? Thank you again

Comment: Yes. You need to null-out the by variable and summarize -- `summary(pairs(con2, by = "contrast"), by = NULL, adjust = "mvt")`

Comment: Thank you again, prof. Lenth. Your help is much appreciated!