# Which equal correlations of three random variables are possible?

Tags: correlation

3 random variables have equal pairwise correlation, what are the possible values of correlation?

I think 1 and 0 are the obvious answers, but are there any more, and how could I find them?

Comment: Do you know the formula to calculate correlation?

Comment: A more general version of this question is addressed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5747.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ be three random variables with common pairwise correlation coefficient $\rho$, that is $\mbox{corr}(X_i, X_j)= \rho$ for $i \neq j$ with $|\rho|\leq 1$. So, the correlation matrix of $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1    & \rho & \rho \\
\rho & 1    & \rho \\
\rho & \rho & 1 \end{array} \right) .
$$
[Correlation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_matrix#Correlation_matrices) need to be [positive-semidefinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-semidefinite_matrix), which implies that [their leading principal minors are all positive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-semidefinite_matrix#Characterizations). So $\rho$ must satisfy the following two conditions
$$
\begin{cases}
1 - \rho^2 &\geq 0,\\
1 - 3\rho^2 + 2\rho^3 &\geq 0 .
\end{cases}
$$
The first condition is always satisfied, and the second condition implies that $\rho \geq -0.5$.

Comment: In case it's not immediately obvious to everyone $1-3\rho^2+2\rho^3 = (1-\rho)^2(1+2\rho)$

Answer (score 3):

Just a side note for the otherwise correct answers already given (+1 both). The correlation/covariance matrix described is *compound symmetric*. This has some rather important theoretical implication on how one interpreters a model; in particular one would assume that the co-variance of the variables examined can be perfectly partitioned in a  "shared" component and the "unshared" component between your variables. 
A (somewhat) common setting for such structures to be used is when the assumption for equal correlation of residuals is plausible; for example when one deals with repeated trials under the same condition in an experiment.

The CV link: "[What is compound symmetry in plain english?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/what-is-compound-symmetry-in-plain-english)" gives a more in-depth presentation of compound symmetry.