# Is there a two-way Friedman's test?

Tags: r, ranks, friedman-test

I have ranked concentrations (from 0 to 5) of 5 different proteins from 3 different locations from the same patient. In total, 15 measures per patient and 61 patients, so 915 observations.

What I'd like to know is if:

- The 3 locations are the same regarding the concentration of the 5 proteins.
- Any protein is present in one specific location in higher concentration.

I think I'd need a two-way Friedman's ANOVA since I have 2 categorical variables (protein and location) and 1 ordinal variable (ranked concentration). My questions are:

1. **How can I run the test in R?**
2. **Is bootstrapping my only solution?**
3. **What about interactions?**
4. **I have read about proportional odds. Could it help?**

To make it clearer, I here is part of the data:

```
  Protein   Location Concentration
    Prot1   Loc1    0
    Prot1   Loc1    0
    Prot1   Loc1    1
    Prot1   Loc1    0
    Prot1   Loc1    0
    Prot1   Loc1    2
    Prot1   Loc1    1
    Prot1   Loc1    1
    Prot1   Loc1    1
    Prot1   Loc2    1
    Prot1   Loc2    0
    Prot1   Loc2    0
    Prot1   Loc2    1
    Prot1   Loc2    1
    Prot1   Loc2    3
    Prot1   Loc2    0
    Prot1   Loc2    0
    Prot1   Loc2    2
    Prot1   Loc2    0
    Prot1   Loc2    0
    Prot1   Loc3    0
    Prot1   Loc3    0
    Prot1   Loc3    0
    Prot1   Loc3    1
    Prot1   Loc3    1
    Prot1   Loc3    2
    Prot1   Loc3    0
    Prot1   Loc3    1
    Prot1   Loc3    1
    Prot1   Loc3    0
    Prot1   Loc3    0
    Prot2   Loc1    1
    Prot2   Loc1    1
    Prot2   Loc1    2
    Prot2   Loc1    0
    Prot2   Loc1    0
    Prot2   Loc1    1
    Prot2   Loc1    0
    Prot2   Loc1    0
    Prot2   Loc1    0
    Prot2   Loc1    2
    Prot2   Loc1    0
    Prot2   Loc2    2
    Prot2   Loc2    2
    Prot2   Loc2    1
    Prot2   Loc2    1
    Prot2   Loc2    0
    Prot2   Loc2    1
    Prot2   Loc2    3
    Prot2   Loc2    0
    Prot2   Loc2    0
    Prot2   Loc2    3
    Prot2   Loc2    0
    Prot2   Loc3    3
    Prot2   Loc3    1
    Prot2   Loc3    2
    Prot2   Loc3    1
    Prot2   Loc3    0
    Prot2   Loc3    1
    Prot2   Loc3    0
    Prot2   Loc3    0
    Prot2   Loc3    0
    Prot2   Loc3    1
    Prot2   Loc3    0
    Prot3   Loc1    1
    Prot3   Loc1    0
    Prot3   Loc1    0
    Prot3   Loc1    0
    Prot3   Loc1    0
    Prot3   Loc1    0
    Prot3   Loc1    1
    Prot3   Loc1    2
    Prot3   Loc1    0
    Prot3   Loc1    0
    Prot3   Loc1    0
    Prot3   Loc2    0
    Prot3   Loc2    0
    Prot3   Loc2    0
    Prot3   Loc2    0
    Prot3   Loc2    0
    Prot3   Loc2    1
    Prot3   Loc2    5
    Prot3   Loc2    1
    Prot3   Loc2    0
    Prot3   Loc2    0
    Prot3   Loc2    0
    Prot3   Loc3    1
    Prot3   Loc3    0
    Prot3   Loc3    0
    Prot3   Loc3    0
    Prot3   Loc3    0
    Prot3   Loc3    5
    Prot3   Loc3    3
    Prot3   Loc3    2
    Prot3   Loc3    0
    Prot3   Loc3    0
    Prot3   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc1    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc2    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot4   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc1    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc2    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
    Prot5   Loc3    0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your data are ordinal ratings, so you need some form of ordinal logistic regression.  But I also gather that your data are not independent ("... 15 measures per patient..."), so that needs to be taken into account as well.  Thus, the appropriate method here is a mixed effects ordinal logistic regression.  In R, mixed effects OLR models can be fit with the [ordinal package](http://www.cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/index.html).

Here is a brief demonstration with your data:

```
prtdf = read.table(text="Protein   Location Concentration
                         Prot1     Loc1     0
                         ...
                         Prot5     Loc3     0", header=T)
```

There are several issues with these data.  First, they are not quite balanced (which is not actually a big deal):

```
with(prtdf, table(Protein, Location))
#        Location
# Protein Loc1 Loc2 Loc3
#   Prot1    9   11   11
#   Prot2   11   11   11
#   Prot3   11   11   11
#   Prot4   11   11   11
#   Prot5   11   11   11
```

Crucially, they are missing a patient ID indicator.  I will make one up, using the assumption that the order within each category is consistent and by patient ID (this may well be totally false in reality, so be forewarned):

```
prtdf$ID = c(1:9, rep(1:11, times=14))
prtdf    = prtdf[,c(4,1:3)]
head(prtdf, 10)
#    ID Protein Location Concentration
# 1   1   Prot1     Loc1             0
# 2   2   Prot1     Loc1             0
# 3   3   Prot1     Loc1             1
# 4   4   Prot1     Loc1             0
# 5   5   Prot1     Loc1             0
# 6   6   Prot1     Loc1             2
# 7   7   Prot1     Loc1             1
# 8   8   Prot1     Loc1             1
# 9   9   Prot1     Loc1             1
# 10  1   Prot1     Loc2             1
tail(prtdf, 12)
#     ID Protein Location Concentration
# 152 11   Prot5     Loc2             0
# 153  1   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 154  2   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 155  3   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 156  4   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 157  5   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 158  6   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 159  7   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 160  8   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 161  9   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 162 10   Prot5     Loc3             0
# 163 11   Prot5     Loc3             0
```

Next, we need to make sure that `ID` and `Concentration` are appropriately categorized as factors.  (Note also that you are missing any `4`'s in `Concentration`.)

```
with(prtdf, table(Concentration))
# Concentration
#   0   1   2   3   4   5 
# 120  26  10   5   0   2 
prtdf$Concentration = factor(prtdf$Concentration, levels=0:5, ordered=T)
prtdf$ID            = factor(prtdf$ID,            levels=1:11)
```

Now we can try to fit a model:

```
library(ordinal)
mod = clmm(Concentration~Protein*Location+(1|ID), data=prtdf, Hess=T, nAGQ=17)
# Warning message:
#   (1) Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined 
# In addition: Absolute convergence criterion was met, but relative criterion was not met
```

That crashed.  The problem seems to be that all the `Concentrations` in `"Prot4"` and `"Prot5"` are 0:

```
aggregate(Concentration~Protein*Location, data=prtdf, function(x){ mean(as.numeric(x)) })
#    Protein Location Concentration
# 1    Prot1     Loc1      1.666667
# 2    Prot2     Loc1      1.636364
# 3    Prot3     Loc1      1.363636
# 4    Prot4     Loc1      1.000000
# 5    Prot5     Loc1      1.000000
# 6    Prot1     Loc2      1.727273
# 7    Prot2     Loc2      2.181818
# 8    Prot3     Loc2      1.636364
# 9    Prot4     Loc2      1.000000
# 10   Prot5     Loc2      1.000000
# 11   Prot1     Loc3      1.545455
# 12   Prot2     Loc3      1.818182
# 13   Prot3     Loc3      2.000000
# 14   Prot4     Loc3      1.000000
# 15   Prot5     Loc3      1.000000
table(prtdf[prtdf$Protein%in%c("Prot4","Prot5"), "Concentration"])
#  0  1  2  3  4  5 
# 66  0  0  0  0  0
```

We'll simply exclude those levels from the analysis:

```
mod2 = clmm(Concentration~Protein*Location+(1|ID), data=prtdf, Hess=T, nAGQ=7,
            subset=!prtdf$Protein%in%c("Prot4","Prot5"))
summary(mod2)
# Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the adaptive Gauss-Hermite 
# quadrature approximation with 7 quadrature points 
# 
# formula: Concentration ~ Protein * Location + (1 | ID)
# data:    prtdf
# subset:  !prtdf$Protein %in% c("Prot4", "Prot5")
# 
#  link  threshold nobs logLik  AIC    niter     max.grad cond.H
#  logit flexible  97   -106.48 238.97 760(2283) 1.06e-04 2.0e+02
# 
# Random effects:
# Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
# ID     (Intercept) 0.5756   0.7587  
# Number of groups:  ID 11 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# ProteinProt2              -0.14342    0.85466  -0.168    0.867
# ProteinProt3              -0.96646    0.92526  -1.045    0.296
# LocationLoc2               0.03622    0.86002   0.042    0.966
# LocationLoc3              -0.17634    0.84245  -0.209    0.834
# ProteinProt2:LocationLoc2  0.96548    1.19393   0.809    0.419
# ProteinProt3:LocationLoc2  0.02491    1.31402   0.019    0.985
# ProteinProt2:LocationLoc3  0.57413    1.18357   0.485    0.628
# ProteinProt3:LocationLoc3  1.13724    1.27533   0.892    0.373
# 
# Threshold coefficients:
#     Estimate Std. Error z value
# 0|1   0.1591     0.6595   0.241
# 1|2   1.6771     0.6904   2.429
# 2|3   2.7789     0.7615   3.649
# 3|5   4.1442     0.9793   4.232
```

Now this does return a result, but because your variables are factors (or multilevel categorical variables), the individual level p-values are not of interest.  You want to know the significance of the factors as a whole.  In particular, I gather you may be interested in knowing if the interaction is significant.  We can test that by fitting an additive model (i.e., without the interaction term) and performing a nested model test:

```
mod2a = clmm(Concentration~Protein+Location+(1|ID), data=prtdf, Hess=T, nAGQ=7,
             subset=!prtdf$Protein%in%c("Prot4","Prot5"))
anova(mod2a, mod2)
# Likelihood ratio tests of cumulative link models:
#   
#       formula:                                      link: threshold:
# mod2a Concentration ~ Protein + Location + (1 | ID) logit flexible
# mod2  Concentration ~ Protein * Location + (1 | ID) logit flexible
# 
#       no.par    AIC  logLik LR.stat df Pr(>Chisq)
# mod2a      9 233.02 -107.51                      
# mod2      13 238.97 -106.48   2.053  4      0.726
```

The interaction does not appear to be significant for these data.  If you also wanted to test the variables in the additive model, that can be conveniently done like so:

```
drop1(mod2a, test="Chisq")
# Single term deletions
# 
# Model:
# Concentration ~ Protein + Location + (1 | ID)
#          Df    AIC    LRT Pr(>Chi)
# <none>      233.02                
# Protein   2 232.44 3.4238   0.1805
# Location  2 229.74 0.7212   0.6973
```

They are not significant in these data either.

To provide explicit answers to your questions:  Although Friedman's test is a one-way test only, ordinal logistic regression is a generalization of the Kruskal-Wallis test, and mixed effects OLR is a generalization of OLR and of Friedman's test.  Bootstrapping is unlikely to help you here.  Ordinal logistic regression is often called the proportional odds model.

Comment: I have a follow up question on this. How do you use the predict function with the model fitted with clmm. with clm, I can use 'predict(clmMod, type = 'class') but when I do this for 'predict(clmmMod, type = 'class'), it gives me some error.

Comment: Off the top of my head, @Crop89, I don't know. You'd have to read the documentation for that.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, How do you specify a Compound Symmetry covariance matrix in `clmm` function

Comment: @Science11, you don't need to.  You just need to specify the random effects correctly.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, Please pardon my ignorance. Can you please elaborate on on your comment, " compound symmetry = correctly specifying random effects" ??. I did not catch this. This is mainly due to my very poor understanding of Random Effects Models.

Comment: @Science11, try [What is compound symmetry in plain english?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15102/) & perhaps [R's lmer cheat sheet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13166/). Otherwise, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple linear regression with interactions to determine relations of proteins, locations (and their interaction) with concentations. Following is the output from the data that you have provided:

```
> summary(lm(Concentration~Protein*Location, data=prtdf))

Call:
lm(formula = Concentration ~ Protein * Location, data = prtdf)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.1818 -0.5455  0.0000  0.0000  4.3636 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                0.66667    0.27918   2.388   0.0182 *
ProteinProt2              -0.03030    0.37645  -0.080   0.9360  
ProteinProt3              -0.30303    0.37645  -0.805   0.4221  
ProteinProt4              -0.66667    0.37645  -1.771   0.0786 .
ProteinProt5              -0.66667    0.37645  -1.771   0.0786 .
LocationLoc2               0.06061    0.37645   0.161   0.8723  
LocationLoc3              -0.12121    0.37645  -0.322   0.7479  
ProteinProt2:LocationLoc2  0.48485    0.51890   0.934   0.3516  
ProteinProt3:LocationLoc2  0.21212    0.51890   0.409   0.6833  
ProteinProt4:LocationLoc2 -0.06061    0.51890  -0.117   0.9072  
ProteinProt5:LocationLoc2 -0.06061    0.51890  -0.117   0.9072  
ProteinProt2:LocationLoc3  0.30303    0.51890   0.584   0.5601  
ProteinProt3:LocationLoc3  0.75758    0.51890   1.460   0.1464  
ProteinProt4:LocationLoc3  0.12121    0.51890   0.234   0.8156  
ProteinProt5:LocationLoc3  0.12121    0.51890   0.234   0.8156  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8375 on 148 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2019,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1263 
F-statistic: 2.673 on 14 and 148 DF,  p-value: 0.001637
```

It shows that protein 4 and 5 are in somewhat higher concentration but their is no difference between any location regarding concentration of protein. Also there is no interaction between location and protein, hence no one protein is preferentially concentrated in any one location.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes the asnwer is that easy that I try to overcomplicate it.

Comment: I know, I just was waiting 1 day to see if somebody give a different asnwer. But I gues it's time. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I've been reading and I don't think a linear regression is the solution. I'll be answering my own question. Let me know what you think.

Comment: -1, this is incorrect. There are 2 problems: (1) the response is ordinal, so linear regression should not be used; (2) the data are independent, so the non-independence needs to be addressed.

Comment: It's what I thought and [I answered my own question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160857/78640). Do you think a Logistic Regression Model would be a valid solution? How can I address the non-independence?

Comment: I agree ordinal regression would be more appropriate, but since there are reasonably large number of levels (5) and presumably they are equidistant at every level, one may use linear regression also. I would like to know how different are OP's results with ordinal versus linear regression here. Also initially OP was going for two-way Friedman's ANOVA and bootstrapping etc and I directed him to regression. Ordinal vs linear regression is a finer detail.

Answer (score -1):

After reading a little bit more, I think I got the answer to my own question.

Since the response variable is ordinal and the other factors are categorical, I shouldn't use simple linear regression, so I've used Logistic Regression Model.

There are two packages in R that can handle ordinal variables: `lrm {rms}` and `polr {MASS}`.

I opted for `lrm` because it shows the p-value for each stimate, but both results are the same.

Following [@rnso](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160341/78640)'s notation (thanks!):

```
> library (rms)

> lrm (Concentration ~ Protein * Location, data = prtdf)

Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = Concentration ~ Protein * Location, data = prtdf)

Frequencies of Responses

  0   1   2   3   5 
120  26  10   5   2 

                      Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                         Ratio Test            Indexes          Indexes       
Obs           163    LR chi2      60.55    R2       0.380    C       0.805    
max |deriv| 0.002    d.f.            14    g        5.173    Dxy     0.610    
                     Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    gr     176.462    gamma   0.644    
                                           gp       0.111    tau-a   0.263    
                                           Brier    0.083                     

                              Coef     S.E.    Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
y>=1                           -0.0288  0.5961 -0.05  0.9615  
y>=2                           -1.4135  0.6168 -2.29  0.0219  
y>=3                           -2.4530  0.6863 -3.57  0.0004  
y>=5                           -3.7741  0.9132 -4.13  <0.0001 
Protein=Prot2                  -0.1834  0.8232 -0.22  0.8237  
Protein=Prot3                  -0.9596  0.8933 -1.07  0.2827  
Protein=Prot4                 -10.4962 58.1844 -0.18  0.8568  
Protein=Prot5                 -10.4962 58.1844 -0.18  0.8568  
Location=Loc2                  -0.1326  0.8291 -0.16  0.8729  
Location=Loc3                  -0.3028  0.8180 -0.37  0.7113  
Protein=Prot2 * Location=Loc2   1.0297  1.1526  0.89  0.3717  
Protein=Prot3 * Location=Loc2   0.1827  1.2607  0.14  0.8848  
Protein=Prot4 * Location=Loc2   0.1326 82.2851  0.00  0.9987  
Protein=Prot5 * Location=Loc2   0.1326 82.2851  0.00  0.9987  
Protein=Prot2 * Location=Loc3   0.6113  1.1413  0.54  0.5923  
Protein=Prot3 * Location=Loc3   1.0436  1.2382  0.84  0.3993  
Protein=Prot4 * Location=Loc3   0.3028 82.2850  0.00  0.9971  
Protein=Prot5 * Location=Loc3   0.3028 82.2850  0.00  0.9971
```

So with the truncated data set I gave, no significant differences are found between protein concentration, location, or their combination.

I've used the guide by the [Institute for digital research and education, UCLA](http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm) for "Ordinal Logistic Regression".

Any other suggestion?

Comment: What is the meaning of coefficients for 'y>=1'  etc?

Comment: This is better than a linear model, but the non-independence needs to be taken into account. That said, this may not merit a downvote.

Comment: @rnso, those are the cutpoint parameters for the ordinal logistic regression model.

Comment: Can you explain it in some more detail, or point to a web reference.