# What model to use for multiple observations per participant with likert ratings

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, likert

We ran a study in which participants were presented with four items (let's call them service requests) and to each of these requests, two user profiles of people who could satisfy those requests were matched. Our participants had to rate each of those matched profiles on four Likert scales, each concerned with different aspects of the matched profiles.

We want to know if factors such as `word length` of the request, `profile bio word length` and `number of past services listed` in the profile are related to how participants rate those profiles. We have multiple observations per participant and the observations themselves are paired in terms of post.

I am assuming we need some kind of mixed effects regression analysis but I'm not sure how to structure the data and/or what model to apply. I'm using R for analysis and, as well as recommendations, a good example to copy as well as pointers to clear tutorials would be helpful.

Comment: You presumably want a mixed-effects version of ordinal logistic regression. I have an example here: [Is there a two-way Friedman's test?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/161872/7290)

Comment: Thanks, but data are Likert scale, so not logistic. There is debate about treating Likert scales as parametric (e.g., http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/can-likert-scale-data-ever-be-continuous/). But seems fine by this: http://pure.au.dk/portal/files/70360382/SimulationPosterJK.pdf. We're using lmer from R's lme4 package with participant as a group (of 8 observations) and nested request within participant (within participant group, 4 requests, each with 2 grouped observations). I think this is OK. See: http://jaredknowles.com/journal/2013/11/25/getting-started-with-mixed-effect-models-in-r.

Comment: Certainly not *binary* logistic regression, but you do need *ordinal* logistic regression. Try reading the linked thread.

Answer (score 1):

A generalised linear mixed model for an ordinal outcome is what you need. This can be fitted with the `ordinal` package in R using the `clmm` which fits a cumulative link mixed model.