# What type of pairwise test does emmeans run?

Tags: r, mixed-model, t-test, lme4-nlme, multiple-comparisons

Can someone please explain what kind of test `emmeans` runs when using the pairs function (is it a paired t-test between levels)?

I have a linear mixed effects model with two fixed effects (A, B) and one random effect (C). I fit this with the lme function from the nlme package:

```
mod = lme(val~ A*B, random = ~1|C, data = df)
```

For each level of A, I want to perform pairwise comparisons for levels of B to check which one dominates. When I run pairs

```
mod.emm = emmeans(mod, ~A*B)
pairs(mod.emm, simple = "B")
```

Does this function take my random effect C into account, the way a paired t-test would?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Here is an illustration of how the model determines the right test. First, create a toy data set and run both a pooled and a paired *t* test:

```r
y = c(7,6,9,3,2,6)

t.test(y[1:3], y[4:6], var.equal = TRUE)
## 
##  Two Sample t-test
## 
## data:  y[1:3] and y[4:6]
## t = 2.4597, df = 4, p-value = 0.06972
## alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
## 95 percent confidence interval:
##  -0.4722133  7.8055467
## sample estimates:
## mean of x mean of y 
##  7.333333  3.666667

t.test(y[1:3], y[4:6], paired = TRUE)
## 
##  Paired t-test
## 
## data:  y[1:3] and y[4:6]
## t = 11, df = 2, p-value = 0.008163
## alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
## 95 percent confidence interval:
##  2.232449 5.100884
## sample estimates:
## mean difference 
##        3.666667
```

Now, I'm going to create two experimental setups:

```
foo1 = data.frame(trt = factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3)), 
                  subj = factor(1:6))
foo1
##   trt subj
## 1   A    1
## 2   A    2
## 3   A    3
## 4   B    4
## 5   B    5
## 6   B    6

foo2 = foo1; foo2$subj = factor(c(1:3,1:3))
foo2
##   trt subj
## 1   A    1
## 2   A    2
## 3   A    3
## 4   B    1
## 5   B    2
## 6   B    3
```

`foo1` has 6 different subjects, each observed once, while `foo2` has 3 subjects, each observed twice. Now with each dataset, I will fit mixed models with exactly the same specs:

```
library(nlme)
mod1 = lme(y ~ trt, random = ~1|subj, data = foo1)
mod2 = lme(y ~ trt, random = ~1|subj, data = foo2)
```

Now let's test the treatment comparison for each model, again with exactly the same call:

```
library(emmeans)
pairs(emmeans(mod1, "trt"))
##  contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
##  A - B        3.67 1.49  4   2.460  0.0697
## 
## Degrees-of-freedom method: containment

pairs(emmeans(mod2, "trt"))
##  contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
##  A - B        3.67 0.333  2  11.000  0.0082
## 
## Degrees-of-freedom method: containment
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that the *t* test and P value for `foo1` is exactly the same as the pooled test; and that these results for `foo2` are exactly the same as the paired test. This works because the `lme` function knows what to do with the relationship between subjects and treatments, and that is what determines the correct test.

If you had three or more treatments in `foo1` or `foo2`, you would obtain several tests, one for each pairwise comparison. And *none* of them would be the same as either the pooled or paired *t* tests. That's because the models use *all* of the data, while the pooled and paired tests use only the data for two treatments at a time. So already we are in a situation where we've moved past those simple hand calculations.

Answer (score 6):

Using the model, it figures out what linear combination $c$ of regression coefficients *b* are needed to estimate the quantities $\theta$ in question. Then it computes that estimate using the regression formula $\hat\theta = c^Tb$ , and its standard error using $SE(\hat\theta) = \sqrt{c^TVc}$ where $V$ is the variance-covariance matrix of $b$, typically obtained from the model via the `vcov()` function. Then it obtains the $t$ ratio $t = \hat\theta / SE(\hat\theta)$.

When you have fitted a mixed model especially,  is not a simple hand-computation formula that you'll find in a basic textbook; that's why you need computer packages to fit the model and obtain these results.

Answer (score 6):

I think there might be some confusion coming from two types of "pairs" here.

The "pairs" you seem to be thinking about are pairs of observations within individuals. In your mixed model, pairs of observations within individuals are effectively taken into account by the random intercepts. Ideally, modeling with random intercepts in that situation improves the precision of coefficient estimates, similarly to the way a paired *t*-test can. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23276/28500) for discussion.

The `pairs()` function in `emmeans` evaluates pairs of estimated marginal means (EMMs), which are predictions from the model. That can be done for any model type supported by `emmeans`, whether the model involved random effects or not. The `pairs()` function just evaluates the differences between all *pairs of EMMs* that meet the specifications you have set. See [this vignette section](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#pairwise).

The `pairs()` function thus doesn't by itself consider paired observations within individuals. It depends on the mixed model to have taken such within-individual pairing into account. It then uses the fixed-effect coefficient estimates and their covariances to get the differences and associated standard errors for all pairwise comparisons of the EMMs that you specify, as the package's author explains in his answer.